# If this is my second Visiting Assistant Professor job, who should I ask for letters?

Tags: recommendation-letter

I'm just looking ahead, but I intend to get 1 letter from my current department chair but am not sure beyond that. Should I include a letter from my graduate advisor no matter what? Should I get a letter from my last job as well (1 from current school, 1 from previous school, 1 from grad school) or 2 from my current one? Or where else should I look?

Comment: What kind of a position are you applying for?  Is it focused more on teaching (in which case reference letters from the two institutions where you have taught will be critical) or research (in which case a letter from your advisor will be critical) or some mixture (in which case you'll probably want both.)

Comment: @BrianBorchers this would form a good answer ;-)

Comment: The best choice depends on the schools you have worked for, what you did there, and where you will apply.  If I were hiring, I would look for the job you didn't get a letter from.  Then I would contact that employer to find out what they think.

Comment: I'd probably be looking for a more teaching focused institution, but those positions seem to be less frequent so I suppose I might need a research based letter as well?